# Ubuntu 16.04 unity has problems with icons and top panel after installing mate-desktop

Tags: 16.04, unity, icons, themes

I install mate desktop on Ubuntu 16.04

```
sudo apt-get install mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
```

Then I uninstall mate

```
sudo apt-get remove mate-core mate-desktop-environment mate-notification-daemon
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

After rebooting system, unity desktop appears like this
[image: Desktop Screenshot]

Application icons and top panel change. How can I restore unity theme?

Answer (score 0):

Problem has been solved. I do

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove *mate*
sudo apt install --reinstall --purge ubuntu-desktop
```

Maybe the first command is not safe and should be

```
sudo apt purge --auto-remove mate-desktop
```

You should try it first.

Comment: I have test it again. Just issuing "sudo apt purge --auto-remove mate-desktop" is OK. No need to reinstall ubuntu-desktop.